# Understanding JobLauncherTestUtils

Tags: spring-batch

I am currently getting to understand `jobLauncherTestUtils`. I have read about it from multiple resources such as following:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/test/JobLauncherTestUtils.html

https://livebook.manning.com/concept/spring/joblaunchertestutils

I wanted to understand when we call `jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob()`, what does it mean by end-to-end testing of job. Does it actually launch the job. If so, then what's the point of testing the job without mocks? If not so, then how does it actually tests a job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanted to understand when we call jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(), what does it mean by end-to-end testing of job.

End-to-End testing means testing the job as a black box based on the specification of its input and output. For example, let's assume your batch job is expected to read data from a database table and write it to a flat file.

And end-to-end test would:

1. Populate a test database with some sample records
2. Run your job
3. Assert that the output file contains the expected records

Without individually testing the inner steps of this job, you are testing its functionality from end (input) to end (output).

`JobLauncherTestUtils` is a utility class that allows you to run an entire job like this. It also allows you to test a single step from a job in isolation if you want.

> Does it actually launch the job.

Yes, the job will be run as if it was run outside a test. `JobLauncherTestUtils` is just an utility class that uses a regular `JobLauncher` behind the scene. You can run your job in unit tests without this utility class.

> If so, then what's the point of testing the job without mocks?

The point of testing a job without mocks is to ensure the job is working as expected with real resources it depends on or interact with. You can always mock a database or a message broker in your tests, but the mocking code could be buggy and does not reflect the real behaviour of a database or a message broker.

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud Ben Hassine  for the answer. As per my understanding , End to End testing and Integration testing are the same right? Does this mean Functional testing functionality of individual steps? Or can it be individual item test for itemreader and itemwriter also? In case of Functional testing do we mock the dependencies or do we just Autowire them?

Comment: Naming is hard, so I think the goal is here to understand the testing requirement and implement it correctly. After that, each person can call the type of test as needed. To me, using mocks implies unit tests. IMO, testing a bach job should test the output of the job based on its input. Now calling this End-to-End test or integration test or functional test is the same.